# MobileNet: High Accuracy On Validation and Poor Prediction Results

Tags: tensorflow, image-classification, mobilenet, tensorflow-model-garden

I am training [MobileNet_v1_1.0_224](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1704.04861.pdf) using TensorFlow. I am using the python scripts present in the [TensorFlow-Slim image classification model library](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/slim) for training. My dataset distribution with 4 classes is as follows:

normal_faces:  **42070**
oncall_faces:  **13563** (People faces with mobile in the image when they're on call)
smoking_faces: **5949**
yawning_faces: **1630**

All images in the dataset are square images and larger than **224x224**

I am using [train_image_classifier.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/slim/train_image_classifier.py) to train the model with following arguments,

```
python train_image_classifier.py \
    --train_dir=${TRAIN_DIR} \
    --dataset_name=custom \
    --dataset_split_name=train \
    --dataset_dir=${DATASET_DIR} \
    --model_name=mobilenet_v1 \
    --batch_size=32\
    --max_number_of_steps=25000
```

After training the model, [eval_image_classifier.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/slim/eval_image_classifier.py) shows an accuracy greater than **95% on Validation set** but when I exported the frozen graph and used it for predictions, it performs very poorly.

I have also tried this [notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/hub/blob/master/examples/colab/tf2_image_retraining.ipynb) but this also produced similar results.

Log: [Training Log](https://pastebin.com/zAsJx3pm)
Plots: [Loss](https://ibb.co/m5H4XQG) and [Accuracy](https://ibb.co/Q808296)

What is the reason for this? How do I fix this issue?

I have seen similar issues on SO but nothing related to MobileNets specifically.

Comment: How are you calling the prediction?

Comment: @NONONONONO I have exported the frozen graph and loading it.

Comment: Are you sure your real world data is properly preprocessed? MobileNet I think requires you to subtract the ImageNet mean from your data.

Comment: Can you give plots of the accuracy per epoch both for Val and train set. Also, can you provide your sample data and preprocessing code?

Answer (score 0):

Did you use a validation set? If so what was the validation accuracy?
If you used a validation set a good way to check if you are doing predictions properly is to run model.predict on the validation set.

Comment: I have updated the question. The validation is split of 10% of the dataset. The accuracy I mentioned in the question is Validation accuracy.